# cURL Error #:SSL_write() error: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry - PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

When I try to send a cURL request, I get the following error:

```
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> * SSL_write() error: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_pending:bad write retry
* Closing connection 0
```

this is the request I am sending:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/services/service-name';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_STDERR => $fp,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Sometimes it works, but other times it gives me the SSL error "Curl Error Number 55".

```
Curl version:   7.84.0 
SSL version:    OpenSSL/1.1.1p
```

On localhost, it works all the time, but on production server "Linux" it keeps giving me the SSL error. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a lot of uncertainty in your question. There are two errors, neither of which you seem to have looked up on the internet (as the description of the Curl error number does have a description). You also don't make very clear when these errors show up and when not. Furthermore, you give one Curl version, but you are running on two systems? Is maybe the production service running on an older SSL version? I'm asking because a little searching shows [this bug report](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6865).

Comment: I have spent hours trying to get anything useful, but nothing, most questions relate to using fwrite, but I am not directly using it here, it is just standard cURL request. the cURL version in the question is the production one which is higher than the one I have on my localhost machine (cURL: 7.64.0, OpenSSL/1.1.1c).

Comment: The bug report was for 2021 on OpenSSL, your version on the server is **older**. I can understand running a older distribution, but I would strongly suggest staying on top security libraries such as OpenSSL. You have shown you can do that with cURL right?

Comment: my test machine has older cURL and OpenSSL versions but works fine, mainly I used to get cURL error number 6: could not resolve host, so I had to use CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS to define the dns ip addresses, and that's where I started to get the SSL error. It is a shared hosting, and tech admins aren't that helpful and insist that's end-point issue, but I know it is not, as I get successful request every time using my localhost without even using CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS. Did mean upgrading OpenSSL?

Comment: Yes, I'd try and see if the OpenSSL version can be upgraded.

Comment: And to add a little bit more, the payload is successfully signed with private key and attached to the $postData using openssl_pkey_get_private and openssl_sign. If it is SSL issue, shouldn't the error appear during using openssl_sign?

Comment: Huh, what? Why? A write error on `ssl3_write_pending` has nothing to do with signing some kind of payload at the application level.

Comment: I don't know, this is the first time I have seen this error, and most articles talk about fwrite which I am not using, the payload is less thank 50kb so not sure why the error appears.

Comment: It's a problem with the socket, not with the data. If the bug is correct then a transmission error won't trigger a resend... or something like that.

Comment: I am running out of ideas, I am going to try to test the upgrade from php 7.2 to php 8 and see how it goes

Comment: In a separate VM I hope, don't forget your backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything I know, the problem was related to DNS using IPv6 instead of IPv4. I forced the cURL request to use IPv4 and haven't received any error since

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```